# How can I join two lists using map?

Tags: perl, list, dictionary, merge

I have such code in Perl:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

my @a = ('one', 'two', 'three');
my @b = (1, 2, 3);
```

I want to see in result this: `@c = ('one1', 'two2', 'three3');`
Is there way I can merge these lists into one?

Answer (score 9):

Assuming that you can guarantee the two arrays will always be the same length.

```
my @c = map { "$a[$_]$b[$_]" } 0 .. $#a;
```

Answer (score 6):

As an alternative, you can use `pairwise` from [`List::MoreUtils`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?List%3a%3aMoreUtils):

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use List::MoreUtils qw( pairwise );

my @a = ( 'one', 'two', 'three' );
my @b = ( 1,     2,     3 );

my @c = do {
    no warnings 'once';
    pairwise { "$a$b" } @a, @b;
};
```

Comment: You do not need to declare `$a` and `$b` -- regardless, you're declaring them at a global scope anyway. Even localizing them doesn't make that much sense.

Comment: _[Axeman](http://stackoverflow.com/users/11289/axeman)_: To suppress warnings, you have to declare them, or disable `once` warnings.

Comment: @Alan Haggai Alavi: I see. I guess in a standard script I use enough sorting that I never encounter that. Regardless, there is no reason to pseudo-localize it in a `do` construct. It makes more sense to do `no warnings 'once'` in that `do`.

Comment: The problem is that `List::MoreUtils` isn’t Standard Perl.

Comment: @Alan Haggai Alavi: No problem. You got the +1 before I made the comment, so this isn't an argument--but a discussion. It's prompted me to compare *saying* you don't want a warning--in a limited scope, to adding extraneous code that might need a comment `# avoid once warning`. That said, I've written code like that, and I often felt that I needed to comment it. After that I figured, if I don't want the warning, just say I don't want it. You know, it's interesting: I resisted Damian's deprecation of `tie`-s from PBP, but since I read the book, I haven't written a single tie in a completed code.

Comment: @Alan Haggai Alavi: However, I have run into the other problem with reviewers who panic because I'm turning a warning off. They act like I'm trying to do something super fancy or to some even unprincipled or illegal.

Comment: _[Axeman](http://stackoverflow.com/users/11289/axeman)_: Thank you for the comments. You are right. `no warnings 'once'` would be more clear. Need to refresh my PBP knowledge. :-)

Comment: _[tchrist](http://stackoverflow.com/users/471272/tchrist)_: True. I was just trying to present an alternative. :-)

Answer (score 1):

For completeness, and to make Tom happy, here is a pure perl implementation of `pairwise` that you can use:

```
use B ();
use List::Util 'min';

sub pairwise (&\@\@) {
    my ($code, $xs, $ys) = @_;
    my ($a, $b) = do {
        my $caller = B::svref_2object($code)->STASH->NAME;
        no strict 'refs';
        map \*{$caller.'::'.$_} => qw(a b);
    };

    map {
        local *$a = \$$xs[$_];
        local *$b = \$$ys[$_];
        $code->()
    } 0 .. min $#$xs, $#$ys
}
```

Since that is a bit involved, it is probably easier to just use `map` as davorg shows.